# Can I permanently change the windows timezone vis ssh and cygwin?

Tags: windows, ssh, remote-desktop, cygwin, automation

I have a bunch of VM's with Windows Server 2008 R2 and ssh running via cygwin. I want to change the timezone on all of them. I would prefer not to RDP to every one of them and do it manually.

I have found these commands will change the timezone:

```
export TZ=GMT
echo $TZ
```

But this doesn't persist when my windows server 2008 restarts.

Any Ideas?

Comment: I'm a little confused.  It appears all you're doing is creating an environment variable named "TZ", setting it to "GMT" and then echoing it.  Which would do nothing to the actual Windows timezone settings..?

Comment: Also you may want to check this SO question out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6444502/how-do-i-set-an-environment-variable-in-cygwin

Comment: You should use windows command   [see as example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16656229/how-do-i-set-the-timezone-from-command-line)